# MYSQL / PHP Calculating number of occurrences

Tags: php, mysql

First off all I am slightly confused what the best implemtentation would be for the following problem i.e pure can it be done with only mysql without altering tables or would I need a combination of PHP and mysql as I am currently doing.
Please keep that in mind as you read on:

**Question Info**

A Pickem game works as follow:

1- Display all matches / fixtures in a round for a tournament.

2- User enters which teams he thinks will win each fixture.

The fixtures are pulled from a table `schedule` and the users results are recorded in a table `picks`

**Keep In mind**

Each round can have a number of matches (anywhere between 1 to 30+ matches)

**What I am trying todo / PROBLEM**

I am trying to calculate how many users selected `team1` to win and how many users selected `team2` to win for a given round in a tournament.

**Example**

*Manchester United: 7 users picked  | 
Arsenal 3: users picked*

**MYSQL TABLES**

***schedule table*** Schedule of upcoming games 
[image]

***picks table*** User Picks are recorded in this table
[image]

**Expected Output From Above Tables After Calculations**

So for Super Rugby Round 1 it should read as follow:

- `gameID 1` 4 picks recorded, 2 users selected Jaquares 1 user Selected Stormers (ignore draw fro now)
- `gameID 2` 4 picks recorded, 4 users selected Sharks, 0 users selected Lions

**My Code**

```
function calcStats($tournament, $week)
{
    global $db;
//GET ALL GAMES IN TOURNAMENT ROUND
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROMpicks
            WHERE picks.tournament = :tournament AND picks.weekNum = :weekNum ORDER BY gameID';
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':tournament', $tournament);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $week);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $picks = $stmnt->fetchAll();
            return $picks;
        }
    return false;
}
```

test.php

```
 $picks = calcStats('Super Rugby', '1');
 foreach($picks as $index=> $pick) {
            if($pick['gameID'] !== $newGameID){
                ?>
                <h1><?php echo $pick['gameID']?></h1>
                <?php
                //reset counter on new match
                $team1 = 0;
                $team2 = 0;
            }
            if($pick['picked'] === $newPick){
                //gameID is passed as arrayKey  to map array index to game ID
                //team name
                $team1[$pick['picked']];
                //number times selected
                $team1Selections[$pick['gameID']] = $team1++;
            }
            else if($pick['picked'] !== $newPick){
                ///gameID is passed as arrayKey  to map array index to game ID
                //team name
                $team2[$pick['picked']];
                $team2Selections[$pick['gameID']] = $team2++;
            }
            $newPick = $pick['picked'];
            $newGameID = $pick['gameID'];
    }
```

`PRINT_R()` **Of function `$picks = calcStats('Super Rugby', '1')`**

[image]

I hoe my question makes sense, if you need any additional information please comment below, thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Edit your question and add table definitions and SQL to populate tables with sample data.

Comment: @ryantxr what do you mean question edit question title?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "0 users selected Lions" -> is that important to be shown in the output, or is it enough to only show the picks?

Comment: Hi @Ja͢ck I'll be displaying / converting the values as percentages -- So I guess it is somewhat important but the chance that 0 users ever select a team will be very small. I can also always simply add a condition which ensures there there is atleast 1 pick for each team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're doing too much within PHP that can be easily done within MySQL; consider the following query:

```
SELECT gameID, team, COUNT(*) AS number_of_picks
FROM picks
WHERE picks.tournament = :tournament AND picks.weekNum = :weekNum 
GROUP BY gameID, team
ORDER BY gameID, team
```

This will give the following results, given your example:

```
1 | Jaquares | 2
1 | Stormers | 1
1 | Draw     | 1
2 | Sharks   | 4
```

Then, within PHP, you perform grouping on the game:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($stmnt->fetchAll() as $row) {
  $result[$row['gameID']][] = $row;
}
return $result;
```

Your array will then contain something like:

```
[
  '1' => [
    [
      'gameID' => 1,
      'team' => 'Jaquares',
      'number_of_picks' => 2,
    ],
      'gameID' => 1,
      'team' => 'Stormers',
      'number_of_picks' => 1,
    ],
    ...
```